# Who is [company name] or Who are [company name]

Tags: grammar

I work at a company and we are redesigning our website. One of the titles of a page is about the company and who we are. There is a huge debate going on regarding how the initial question should be phrased...

Who is [Company name]
Who are [Company name]

I should also mention that our company name is in a plural form. Whether this makes a difference or not is also up for debate.

Looking forward to hearing peoples suggestions.

Comment: +1 Nice question. You're going to get a lot of answers! I'd wait a day or two before selecting any.

Comment: This is almost an exact copy of [The company is/are conundrum](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/204393/the-company-is-are-conundrum), which is itself a duplicate.